# Querying each element of a list

Tags: prolog, artificial-intelligence

I am doing homework for AI class and I am writing a prolog program.

I am supposed to take a list of names and check if each person in the list belongs to a specific country chosen.

what i have so far

```
% facts
person(bruce, australia, rhodri, bronwyn).
person(rhodri, newyork, dan, mary).
person(bronwyn, miami, gar, roo).
person(dan, miami, george, mimi).
person(mary, texas, mack, tiki).
person(gar, jamaica, zid, rem).
person(roo, newzealand, john, jill).

person(tom, mayday, dick, mel).
person(dick, newyork, harry, rin).
person(mel, miami, tom, stacey).
person(harry, miami, george, mimi).
person(rin, texas, mack, tiki).
person(tom, jamaica, zid, rem).
person(stacey, newzealand, john, jill).

% rules

eligible(P,C) :-
   person(P, C, F, M) , !
 ; person(F, C, Newfather, Newmother), !
 ; person(M, C, Newfather, Newmother), !
 ; person(Newfather, C, Grandfather , Grandmother), !
 ; person(Newmother, C, Grandfather, Grandmother).

checkteam([] , C). 
checkteam([H|T] , C) :- eligible(H, C) , checkteam(T, C).
```

the last two lines in particular i am having issues with, i am trying to test each member of the list with the eligible() function then let the first element of tail become the head and repeat.

I cant figure out a way to test each member and then display a fail if any of the members are not eligible or true if all members belong to that country.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: was fooling around and changed the code a little, as for results

```
?- checkteam([bruce, dan], mayday).
true.
```

even though neither bruce or dan are from mayday or any parents or grandparents that do.

Comment: You should be getting multiple warnings when you try to compile this; why are you ignoring them? And what is `eligible` supposed to do, exactly?

Comment: And anyway, `[H|T] = T` is always going to fail, because `[H|T]` will not unify with `T`.

Comment: eligible checks if the person or parents or grandparents belong to that specific country. I didnt get any errors as far as i saw, just got incorrect results. I was experimenting with [H|T] = T to try to get the new head and tail excluding the current one.

Comment: This exact program gives me an error and a warning in SWI-Prolog. If you don't see them you should correct your question to the actual program you have. Also, show the results and explain how they are wrong.

Comment: I fixed the error i think( was a space in a country name) i also posted the incorrect result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `eligible` predicate doesn't make sense to me (probably I am misunderstanding). But, if `person` is defined as `person(Name, Country, Father, Mother)` then it could be:

```
eligible(Name, Country) :- person(Name, Country, _, _).
eligible(Name, Country) :- person(Name, _, Father, _),
                           person(Father, Country, _, _).
eligible(Name, Country) :- person(Name, _, _, Mother),
                           person(Mother, Country, _, _).
```

Then your `checkteam` should still give you a warning. Put an underscore at the beginning of the variable name to get rid of it:

```
checkteam([], _Country).
```

Comment: Thanks, that looks good, didnt think of that. Gonna try it and see. not sure if this fixes the issue of the checkteam not checking each member though. EDIT: WOW, it worked :O. Thanks lots man.